# Trying to fetch the last inserted record in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on "Invoice table". It has "invoice_id" and "amount" fields. I need to fetch the latest value of "amount" of the latest inserted "invoice_id"

Code is :

```
$camount = $this->db->select_max('invoice_id')->get_where('invoice', array('invoice_id' => $this->input->post('invoice_id')))->row()->amount;
```

Comment: use `order by desc` on `primary` key column.

Answer (score 0):

You cab use `order by des`c on `primary key` column as below

Note: if primary key is `invoice_id` then why you are putting in where condition?

```
// add your where conditions e.g: $this->db->where('Field / comparison', 'value');

        $this->db->order_by('invoice_id', 'desc');
        $invoice = $this->db->get('invoice')->row_array();
        if($invoice){
            $camount = $invoice['amount'];
        }
```